# How to optimize below update query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2016, query-performance

I have the below update query, its taking around 3 minutes to execute, I have around 1.5 million records present in "Data" table and 100000 records present in "Report" table, can someone help me in optimizing similar kind of update queries.

```
Update [Data] set [Invoice Number]=S.[invoice No],
[Invoice Date]=S.[Invoice date],[From]=S.[From],
[To]=S.[To],[Code]=S.[code] 
from [Data] A inner join 
[Report] S on RTRIM(LTRIM(A.[Order ID]))=RTRIM(LTRIM(S.[Order ID])) and S.UniqueID=' ABC'
where A.[Final Status]='Valid' and A.UniqueID='ABC'
```

Answer (score 2):

Applying functions to columns in `WHERE` and `JOIN` clause predicates prevents indexes from being used efficiently.

`RTRIM` is unnecessary since trailing spaces are ignored during string comparison so that can be removed.

Update the underlying data to remove leading `[Order ID]` spaces so the `LTRIM` is unnecessary in queries. You can then modify the `JOIN` clause can specify `A.[Order ID] = S.[Order ID]`. This may improve query performance significantly, assuming you also have appropriate indexes in place.

Comment: A great answer for not so great question. We not sure what types are "Order ID". What's more have no idea about indexes. Having indexes on 'Final Status' and 'UniqueId' helps too.